# android studio 2.2.3 run button disabled

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a big problem with my Android studio, I followed many tutorials and it doesn't work .

I need your help...
Here are some photos to describe my problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, your problem is not clear

Comment: I would guess there is a problem with the SDK or with the Manifest or Gradle preventing you to build the project..

Answer (score 0):

1. Try building your project.
2. Make sure your project's name doesn't have any special charactrers in its name.
3. Try creating another project and copying everything you did into it.
   Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

click the button(below menu item Run) left of Run Button, if possible, then choose app.

or

Rebuild and Run.